# Angular2 throws "has changed after it was checked" error

Tags: angular

I get an error from the second run of change detection in development mode but bindings do not change so I suspect it might be a bug.

Here is the plunk;

http://plnkr.co/edit/CXQq2lAriwZuzYZoMF3D?p=info

Tester simple creates an embedded view from a template element and sets a local variable.

```js
import {Component,ElementRef,AfterViewInit,TemplateRef,ContentChild,ViewContainerRef,EmbeddedViewRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'p-tester',
    template: ''
})
export class Tester  {

    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) tmpl: TemplateRef;

    constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let view = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.tmpl);
        view.setLocal('\$implicit', 'Optimus');
    }
}
```

Using it throws the error;

```
<div>
  <p-tester>
    <template #name>
      {{name}}
    </template>
  </p-tester>
```

The text Optimus is displayed fine but console has the error.

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7443

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen the similar issues at github, only possible workaround is production mode which is not ideal.

Comment: Just as reference in case the issue gets information added, to make it easier to find from here.